# Как подключить QDBusConnection К dbus под windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt5

Поднял dbus-demon для локальной сессии tcp:host=localhost,port=12345 nmap показывает, что на этом порте висит этот демон. Прописал переменную окружения DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS tcp:host=localhost,port=12345. dbus-monitor.exe говорит, что есть сервер. А из QT пробую подключиться и не дает выдает ошибку org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Disconnected. Подскажите в каком направлении искать мануалы?

```
qDebug() << QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment().value("DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS");
if (!QDBusConnection::sessionBus().isConnected()) {
    qDebug()<< QDBusConnection::sessionBus().lastError();
    //qDebug() << QDBusConnection::sessionBus().name();
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot connect to the D-Bus session bus.\n"
        "To start it, run:\n"
        "\teval `dbus-launch --auto-syntax`\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Update:

```
QDBusConnection connection= QDBusConnection::connectToBus(QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment().value("DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS"),"dbus");
if (!connection.isConnected())
{
    qDebug() << connection.lastError();
    int i;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Я в этом коде не вижу коннекта к демону, это не весь код? Покажите весь код.

Comment: Я так же пробовал подключиться `QDBusConnection connection= QDBusConnection::connectToBus(QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment().value("DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS"),"dbus");
 if (!connection.isConnected())
 {
  qDebug() << connection.lastError();
  int i;
  i++;
 }` Но результат был тот же самый.

Comment: Код добавляйте в вопрос, в комментариях он трудночитаем

Comment: Вынес код в тело вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос. В переменной окружения PATH должен быть путь к dbus-1.dll